# How do I use the category name rather than the category id in my url?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, routes, pyrocms

I am using the CodeIgniter framework and am having trouble figuring out how to get my urls to display the category name but still have my queries reference the category id.

I have a controller set up called jobs. The structure of the url is "example.com/jobs/listings/category_id" example: "example.com/jobs/listings/3" where 3 would be the category id for "software".

I'd rather the url say "example.com/jobs/listings/category_name" example: "example.com/jobs/listings/software".

The problem I'm running into is that the "jobs" table holds stores the category_id that the job belongs to and not the category_name. I have a separate table that holds just the category id's and their names. I'm not sure how to A.) Write my query and B.) Make an SEO friendly url structure.

My current query looks something like "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE cat_id = 3;

Also, I'm not sure if I should be using mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file or if I should be using the routes.php file in CodeIgniter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join to your other table.

```
SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN categories ON jobs.cat_id = categories.id WHERE categories.name = ?;
```

Make sure to put a unique key on the category name, if you don't have one already.

`mod_rewrite` is a poor solution to app routing and wouldn't help much here anyway.  Stick to whatever your framework provides.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html at URL_title()

Convert you category name using the url_title() function making sure you have no duplicates.

When a url is called Look up your category from your model using a simple where statement

Eg

```
$this->db->from('categories');
$this->db->where('name', $url);
Etc...
```

Use this to load your page titles etc then use the categoryid returned to do the look up on your jobs table.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about url_title(). That did help me. I wish I could choose both answers because they both helped. I will give you a +1 though ;)